# JS ClipboardEvent clipboardData always empty

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I want to recieve files via CTRL+V from the ClipboardEvent in Angular6.
But the clipboardData is always empty (I tested images and text).
I tested it on the latest Chrome/Firefox release.

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot, the files/items attribute is empty.
This is my current code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    document.addEventListener('paste', this.pasteEvent);
  }

  private pasteEvent(e): void {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Comment: The `files` and `items` are live data, so once you look at it in the developer console it may be gone already. At least this is my interpretation, since when looping over the `files` and `items` logging them individually I see data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might not be possible because of security restrictions and varying browser support.

To get data from your event you have to call `getData(format)` on [clipboardData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData) passing the desired MIME type (or just 'Text' for text). E.g.

```
private pasteEvent(e): void {
  console.log(e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
}
```

to get text. I'm not sure if you can get files anyway.

Current Chrome also supports the new [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard):

```
private async pasteEvent(e)  {
  const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  console.log(text);
}
```

The generic `read()` method is not supported though.

Comment: Thank you for your answere! The correct getter is `getData`. Can you pls edit your answere? ;)

Comment: Note that if you save the `ClipboardEvent` in the chrome console then try to call `getData` on it, that won't work. This caught me out while trying different ways of accessing the clipboard. Using `getData` within the `pasteEvent` method does work though.